# Validation with pattern in angular 2 forms

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an `Ionic 2` app which has form validation. A field where only digits are allowed has this validation within the form group declaration .

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  number: ['', Validators.pattern('\d*')],
});
```

But it is showing an error in the form field when I give an input like `333` . What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

try this /^\d+$/;
let me know if worked